# helm creates no output if writing to file

Tags: kubernetes-helm

This creates output:

```
❯ helm template cilium/cilium --version 1.14.3 | head

---
# Source: cilium/templates/cilium-agent/serviceaccount.yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: ServiceAccount
metadata:
  name: "cilium"
  namespace: org-demo
---
# Source: cilium/templates/cilium-operator/serviceaccount.yaml
apiVersion: v1
```

But this creates no output:

```
❯ helm template cilium/cilium --version 1.14.3 > o

❯ cat o
```

What could be the reason for that?

Background: I use Linux since 1996 and just don't get this.

Environment:

- Ubuntu 22.04
- vscode terminal.

Answer (score 0):

This must be a crazy bug in `snap`.

After installing it via homebrew, it worked as expected.